# How can I print text bracket characters, whatever their position?

Tags: characters

Consider this snippet (to be inserted in, say, article class):

```
\begin{itemize}
\item one [two]
\item [one] two
\item $[$one$]$ two
\end{itemize}
```

And the corresponding rendering:

[image]

This clearly shows that, although the `[` and `]` bracket characters are not listed as reserved characters [over here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#Reserved_Characters), they cleary are processed in a special way, as the second line shows. The content seems to be treated as an option to the `\item` command.

The third line shows an attempt to produce the desired output, but it is also clear that it does not get rendered as the one on first line.

Questions:

1. how can I produce  "text" brackets whatever their localisation?
2. shall I add these to the list of reserved characters on the linked page ? I would say yes, but maybe there are some aspects I do not see.

PS: yes, as you may have figured out, this is rendered with `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, thus the bullet shape.

Comment: Should we guess you have `\usepackage{mathpazo}` or maybe you can expose the secret? `;-)`

Comment: Use e.g. `\item \relax [one] two` so that the brackets are not interpretated as optional argument.

Comment: @Werner Good spot, didn't find it myself, indeed a duplicate, AFAIK. Can you tag it ?

Comment: @egreg  ??? Sorry, I don't see your point. No I don't use `mathpazo`...

Comment: A bit surprising that the OP himself classifies his posting as a duplicate, even though none of his questions are answered there: How to get robust text brackets regardless where they appear, and whether brackets should be also listed as special characters, on a par with #, % etc.

Comment: @gernot Well, no, not that suprising: the linked answer cleary gives two solutions `\item{}[aaa]` or  `\item \relax [aaa]`. But it's true that 1-not sure that this works in **every** situations, and 2-nobody answered my second question...

Comment: re your second question, the latex wikibook is far from perfect.  it could be useful to have the information that brackets are *in some situations* treated in a special way, namely in a position where an option may be specified.  they should *not* be grouped with either of the existing lists.